# Generic contentful server error from GraphQL Query - when query is ran against a large amount of entries

Tags: graphql, apollo, contentful

I am getting a contentful internal server error when running queries against large amounts of entries even though i am using query limits.

```
Operation : {
  variables: {
    limit: 10,
    skip: 0,
    locale: 'en-GB',
    competition: '2w9CJm2sLwCUAwFjUlvxKU',
    category: '2bkKAjcRcsJWw3TVQuzNnJ'
  },
  extensions: {
    persistedQuery: {
      version: 1,
      sha256Hash: '00755eb0c141056e61b73a54cc917624d1cfa25f58a2903555fabd893f9ab46e'
    }
  },
  operationName: 'GetNewArticlesQuery',
  query: {
    __meta__: { hash: '55a8405e5ff1b9cd6d5dd1271440e6c670ba7d75' },
    kind: 'Document',
    definitions: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}
```

The query

```
query {
    articlePageCollection(where: {
    category: { sys: { id: "xxx" } } # 1500 entries
    competition: { sys: { id: "xxx" }} # 22005 enties 
  }, limit: 12, locale: "en-GB", order: [publishDate_DESC]) {
    skip
    limit
    total
    items {
      sys {
        id
      }
      # attributes
    }
  }
}
```

The query is successful if the category and competition have a small amounts entries.

Has anyone else has something similar

Answer (score 0):

in case of a internal server error you should open a support ticket. There could be something wrong on their side. Otherwise you would receive a more specific error.